# How can I generate a 3d model via a series of transforms?

Tags: 3d, unity, models, blender

Is it possible to generate 3D models using some sort of object transformation (like it's shown [here](http://i-simplicity.de/tutorials.html#asteroid)), using PovRay or any other tool, and import them into Blender / Unity?

For example starting with a primitive sphere:

[image]

And applying a series of transforms/noise to generate something like:

[image]

Then baking them in, resulting in a 3D model of an asteroid that can be used in game.

Comment: sorry, already clarified the question.

Comment: Blender seems to be able to do this for terrain meshes. Why not for closed meshes? http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Deforming/Noise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should actually be able to do this within Blender using a Python scripting. There are plenty of functions available for [modifying meshes](http://www.blender.org/documentation/248PythonDoc/Mesh.Mesh-class.html). You should be able to follow the tutorial you provided, converting the methods into Python and adapting them to modify a mesh of your choosing.

Alternatively, you could write a application in your language of choice. Perform the operations described in the tutorial on an array of vertices. Finally, output the vertices into one of the popular formats that Blender imports and import the mesh into Blender for further manipulation or whatever you end goal is.

It does appear you can go from [PovRay to Blender](http://news.povray.org/povray.general/thread/%3C47f4ce2d@news.povray.org%3E/) if your scene is made entirely of meshes. I don't know much about PovRay, but I don't see any indicator that the tutorial uses meshes, so you may be out of luck there.

Comment: @Fableal, don't be so quick to accept. You're less likely to get more varied answers if you accept on too soon. Wait a day, see what comes up, you may get a better answer. You can up-vote to show you like an answer.

Comment: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" :(